# Draw specific networks with edge weights from adjacency matrix

Tags: python, networkx

I would like to draw a network with edges weights directly from the adjacency matrix with specific communities etc

I could define the weights using ['weight'] however, it seems the draw function does not understand

```
C = np.array([[1,1,0,1,1,0,0,0,0],[0,1,1,0,1,1,0,0,0],[0,0,0,1,1,0,1,1,0],[0,0,0,0,1,1,0,1,1]])

H = C*0.25

dimension_y,dimension_x = H.shape

observation_based_state_graph = np.dot(np.transpose(H),H)

for i in range(dimension_x):
    observation_based_state_graph[i,i] = 0

G_state=nx.from_numpy_matrix(observation_based_state_graph)


communities_generator = community.asyn_fluidc(G_state,2)


edges = G_state.edges()
weights = [G_state[u][v]['weight'] for u,v in edges]

community_list_x = [[0,1,2,3],[5,6,7,8],[4]]    
labels = {}
labels[0] = '0'
labels[1] = '1'
labels[2] = '2'
labels[3] = '3'
labels[4] = '4'
labels[5] = '5'
labels[6] = '6'
labels[7] = '7'
labels[8] = '8'


pos=nx.spring_layout(G_state)
nx.draw_networkx_nodes(G_state,pos,
                       nodelist=community_list_x[0],
                       node_color='r',
                       node_size=500,
                   alpha=0.8)
nx.draw_networkx_nodes(G_state,pos,
                       nodelist=community_list_x[1],
                       node_color='b',
                       node_size=500,
                   alpha=0.8)
nx.draw_networkx_nodes(G_state,pos,
                       nodelist=community_list_x[2],
                       node_color='g',
                       node_size=500,
                   alpha=0.8)
nx.draw_networkx_edges(G_state,pos,width=weights,alpha=0.5)
nx.draw_networkx_labels(G_state, pos, labels, font_size=16)

labels = nx.get_edge_attributes(G_state,'weight')
nx.draw_networkx_edge_labels(G_state,pos,edge_labels=labels)

plt.show()
```

In the output figure, all edges width are uniform. However, I have checked that the weight vector contains elements of different values

Answer (score 0):

I think you need to scale your weights a bit to see the difference.
Note, I multiplying by 100.

```
nx.draw_networkx_edges(G_state,pos,width=[i*100 for i in weights],alpha=0.5)
```

Output:

[image]